# How to find rows in a dataframe that show unique results across multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

This might be a simple answer, but I am having issues finding this solution and could use help, please.

```
> fruit.names <- c(rep("apple",3), rep("pear",3), rep("pepper", 3), rep("rice",3))
> adj <- c(rep("red", 3), rep("not round", 2), "yellow", rep("hot", 3), "grain", "white", "starch")
> df.start <- data.frame(fruit.names, adj)
> df.start
   fruit.names       adj
1        apple       red
2        apple       red
3        apple       red
4         pear not round
5         pear not round
6         pear    yellow
7       pepper       hot
8       pepper       hot
9       pepper       hot
10        rice     grain
11        rice     white
12        rice    starch
```

I am need of code that results that list only unique df.start$names and has all the **same** results in df.start$adj for each item in df.start$names.

So the results would look like this.  I'd prefer to use only base R, if possible (i.e. no tidyr/dplyr.)

```
> df.results
 fruit.names     adj
1   apple        red
2   pepper       hot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple ways:

### base R

```r
ind <- ave(df.start$adj, df.start$fruit.names, FUN = function(z) length(unique(z)) == 1) == "TRUE"
unique(df.start[ind,])
#   fruit.names adj
# 1       apple red
# 7      pepper hot
```

The need to check against the *string* `"TRUE"` is because `ave` requires that its return value is the same class as the input vector, so the output is coerced.

### dplyr

(Offered for the crowd, though I know you said you preferred base R.)

```r
library(dplyr)
df.start %>%
  group_by(fruit.names) %>%
  filter(length(unique(adj)) == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct()
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   fruit.names adj  
#   <chr>       <chr>
# 1 apple       red  
# 2 pepper      hot
```

Comment: @r2evens Thank you!  I'd assume that the ave() solution would work with a 3rd column too?

Comment: If the third column is another grouping column, then you can add it to the second argument, as in `df.start[,c("fruit.names","othercol")]`. But if you have (say) `adj2` (another column that needs uniqueness), then more trickery may be required using `ave`.